# WordPress site copy

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to create a copy of Wordpress site [steakchamp.com](http://steakchamp.com) to another domain [steakchamp.cz](http://steakchamp.cz).
I do not have access to original site, but I have a database export and full files and folders backup (hopefully).
I changed all URLs in the database and in all files and uploaded that to the new domain. It works partly, but I get these errors:

> Warning: realpath(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is
>   not within the allowed path(s):
>   (/www/doc/www.steakchamp.cz:/disk2/doc/www.steakchamp.cz:/usr/share/php:/www/tmp:/tmp)
>   in
>   /www/doc/www.steakchamp.cz/www/wp-content/plugins/widgetkit/helpers/path.php
>   on line 202

I have also tried to check 
`wp-content/uploads` options
change

```
DEFINE('WP_TEMP_DIR','../tmp');
```

but nothing works for me.

Comment: According to the error there might be double url like `http://example.com/example.com`. check your DB again

Comment: Checked for steakchamp.cz/steakchamp.cz and nothing like that there. Thank you anyway!